# Dynamic validation of sub-options in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Let's say I have the following options structure

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public record AzureOption
{
    public AzureGraphOption? Graph { get; init; }
}

public record AzureGraphOption
{
    public AzureGraphSecretOption? Secret { get; init; }
}

public record AzureGraphSecretOption
{
    [Required] public string TenantId { get; init; }
    [Required] public string ClientId { get; init; }
    [Required] public string ClientSecret { get; init; }
}
```

And an extension class:

```cs
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.Graph;

public static class AzureServiceExtensions
{
    // Add Azure services so we can query the Microsoft Graph and resolve membership for automatic group assignment
    public static IServiceCollection AddAzureServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAzureOptions();

        // Add a Azure Token Credentials based on "static" credentials
        // Requires a working Azure app and approvals for several permissions.
        // The app does not have to be operating on behalf of the user.
        services.AddScoped<TokenCredential>(provider =>
        {
            var azureOption = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<AzureOption>>().CurrentValue;

            return new ClientSecretCredential(
                azureOption.Graph?.Secret?.TenantId,
                azureOption.Graph?.Secret?.ClientId,
                azureOption.Graph?.Secret?.ClientSecret,
                new TokenCredentialOptions
                {
                    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
                });
        });

        // Add the Microsoft Graph Service, based on the Azure Token
        services.AddScoped(provider => new GraphServiceClient(provider.GetService<TokenCredential>(),
            new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }));
        
        return services;
    }

    public static IServiceCollection AddAzureOptions(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions<AzureOption>()
            .BindConfiguration("Azure")
            .ValidateDataAnnotations()
            .ValidateOnStart();

        return services;
    }
}
```

And a small utility extension class:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddSecretConfig(this IConfigurationBuilder config)
    {
        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.Secret.json", true, true);
        return config;
    }
}
```

We can also bootstrap a little ASP.NET Core app for testing, if you will:

```cs
using WebApplication = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddSecretConfig();

builder.Services
    .AddAzureServices();

var app = builder.Build();
app.Run();
```

I also have a small structure of secret file stored as `appsettings.Secret.json` in web root:

```json
{
  "Azure": {
    "Graph": {
      "Secret": {
        "TenantId": "30cbfa3f-a625-436a-90ff-e90c3fe8bb8e",
        "ClientId": "37c72790-ee45-4090-a749-c3ff61c43df8",
        "ClientSecret": "qqBGA~5QYza42ABjeWx4o-kAQPJKAGD38wVXCR7Y"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It all went good and well, until I decided to delete the secrets:

```json
{
  "Azure": {
    "Graph": {
      "Secret": {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, the app still runs, and does not validate for the fields of `Azure:Graph:Secret`, because it is now `null` instead. Thus the `Required` validations attached on the fields never runs. If you have added a wrong property in `Azure:Graph:Secret`, this will happen too:

```cs
var azureOption = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<AzureOption>>().CurrentValue;
var tenant = azureOption.Graph.Secret.TenantId; // What???! it is null???!
```

Of course, this is not desirable. I wanted to have this run dynamically:

```
var azureOption = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<AzureOption>>().CurrentValue;
var tenant = azureOption.Graph.Secret.TenantId; // Throws an exception `Required value is not set` instead, while I don't have to handle nullable
```

One can always choose to add the nested options to match:

```cs
    public static IServiceCollection AddAzureOptions(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions<AzureOption>()
            .BindConfiguration("Azure")
            .ValidateDataAnnotations()
            .ValidateOnStart();

        services.AddOptions<AzureGraphSecretOption>()
            .BindConfiguration("Azure:Graph:Secret")
            .ValidateDataAnnotations()
            .ValidateOnStart();

        return services;
    }
```

But doing so is very tedious especially when you have tons of options.

Answer (score 1):

Validation does not run recursively.

When your App is run it tries validate `AzureOption` instance. Class `AzureOption` does not have constraints, in this case validation excute with Success result.

You can define new `MyRecursiveValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute` that run validation of property value recurvively.

It seems like this (not very clean, but works):

**Define new class**

```cs
public class MyRecursiveValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object? value)
    {
        var isValid = true;

        if (value == null)
        { return isValid; }

        isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(value, new ValidationContext(value), null);

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

**Modify your classes**

```cs
public record AzureOption
{
    [MyRecursiveValidation]
    public AzureGraphOption? Graph { get; init; }
}

public record AzureGraphOption
{
    [MyRecursiveValidation]
    public AzureGraphSecretOption? Secret { get; init; }
}

public record AzureGraphSecretOption
{
    [Required] public string TenantId { get; init; }
    [Required] public string ClientId { get; init; }
    [Required] public string ClientSecret { get; init; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on some online resources and SO, I have made myself a reference answer, but I don't think this is the best way to do it, because it is "intrusive":

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Immutable;

public class ValidateObjectAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            var nullable = validationContext.ObjectType
                .GetMember(validationContext.MemberName!)
                .FirstOrDefault()?.CustomAttributes.Any(x => x.AttributeType.Name == "NullableAttribute") ?? false;
            return nullable ? ValidationResult.Success! : new ValidationResult($"{validationContext.DisplayName} is null");
        }

        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(value, new ValidationContext(value, null, null), results, true);

        if (results.Count > 0)
        {
            var compositeResults = new CompositeValidationResult($@"Validation for ""{validationContext.DisplayName}"" failed!");
            results.ForEach(compositeResults.AddResult);
            return compositeResults;
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success!;

    }
}

public class CompositeValidationResult : ValidationResult
{
    public IImmutableList<ValidationResult> Results { get; private set; } = ImmutableList<ValidationResult>.Empty;

    public CompositeValidationResult(string errorMessage) : base(errorMessage) { }
    public CompositeValidationResult(string errorMessage, IEnumerable<string> memberNames) : base(errorMessage, memberNames) { }
    protected CompositeValidationResult(ValidationResult validationResult) : base(validationResult) { }

    public void AddResult(ValidationResult validationResult) => Results = Results.Add(validationResult);
}
```

Then you use it like:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public record GiteaOption
{
    [Required] public required string BaseUrl { get; init; }
    [ValidateObject]
    public GiteaSecretOption? Secret { get; init; } 
}

public record GiteaSecretOption
{ 
    [Required] public required string AccessToken { get; init; }
}
```

Now if `Secret` is not declared to have nullable and is not null, it will also validate the nested class as well.